# how react lifecycle works for components

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I'm working on a react application. There is a main app which creates child components. 
e.g.

```
app
rend(){
   <component1/>
   <component2/>
   <component3 sendMethodDown={this.sendMethodDownToChild}/>
   <component4 sendStateDownState={this.state.sendStateDownState}/>
}
```

When rendering, a method is sent down to child component3. component3 sends specific data back up to app, and then this data is sent to component4.
The data is used in ag-grid.In component4 the data wont be shown until componentDidUpdate stage of lifecycle.

I only want this data to be applied once, it doesn't seem to work when i apply this in componentwillrecieveprops (infinite loop + doesnt apply properly). i managed to get it working by putting it in componentDidUpdate (and using an if statement with boolean state (boolean switch turns off inside the if statement so it never gets run again)

even though this works if not the best. I was thinking of trying to add this back somewhere higher up the lifecycle

There is currently nothing wrong with my app, but I want to improve it. Can anyone help me understand how the react life cycles works when using child components?

is there a life cycle for each component (including app), where app life cycle is paused while the life cycle for the child components finishes?

Comment: Can you show us more of your code?

Comment: Each component only knows about their own lifecycle hooks, so there isn't a lifecycle hook that you can use on the parent to wait for the child components to update. You should wait for the data to be update from your 3rd component before rendering component4. `{!loadingData && <Component4 />}` That way you can control when the data gets loaded into the component.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @ChaseDeAnda, could you elaborate a little about what loadingData is? I assume it isn't some predefined function since i couldn't find any reference to it on google. My assumption is you meant that in component3, i should set something up in componentDidMount that will past a boolean back up to parent level where component4 will only be rendered when the new boolean is returned?

Comment: Yep exactly! `loadingData` could be a piece of state stored in the parent component. Default set to `true`. When component3 finishes doing whatever, it should call a parent function that sets the parent state `loadingData` to false and then component4 should render with the data.